# Changing partial templates using spree-multi-domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, spree

I have a spree store using [spree-multi-domain](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-multi-domain) and the readme has instructions on how to switch the layout file

> these layouts should be located in your site's theme extension in the app/views/spree/layouts/store#code/ directory. So, if you have a store with a code of "alpha" you should store its default layout in app/views/spree/layouts/alpha/spree_application.html.erb

This works fine but now I am not sure how I can change the other templates like `home/index.html.erb`. As I understand these files are rendered into the `yield` part of the layout template but I am unsure how I can set different templates for the different domains using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the answer from gonzalo moreno caballero so it works on rails 5.1

Just store your views like

> app/views/spree/first_store/home/index.html.erb
>
> app/views/spree/second_store/home/index.html.erb

And add this to config/initializers/multi_domain.rb

```
module PartialRendererMultiStore
  def find_template(path, locals)
    prefixes = path.include?(?/) ? [] : @lookup_context.prefixes

    store_prefixes = prefixes
    store_path     = path

    if @view.respond_to?(:current_store) && @view.current_store && !@view.controller.is_a?(Spree::Admin::BaseController)
      store_prefixes = (store_prefixes.map { |i| i.gsub('spree/', "spree/#{@view.current_store.code}/") } + store_prefixes).uniq unless store_prefixes.nil?
      store_path     = store_path.gsub('spree/', "spree/#{@view.current_store.code}/") unless store_path.nil?
    end

    begin
      @lookup_context.find_template(store_path, store_prefixes, true, locals, @details)
    rescue ::ActionView::MissingTemplate
      @lookup_context.find_template(path, prefixes, true, locals, @details)
    end
  end
end


class ActionView::PartialRenderer
  prepend PartialRendererMultiStore
end

module TemplateRendererMultiStore
  def find_template(name, prefixes = [], partial = false, keys = [], options = {})
    if prefixes.nil?
      store_prefixes = nil
    elsif @view.respond_to?(:current_store) && @view.current_store && !@view.controller.is_a?(Spree::Admin::BaseController)
      spree = /^spree\//

      store_prefixes = []

      prefixes.each do |i|
        store_prefixes << i.gsub(spree, "spree/#{@view.current_store.code}/") if i.match(spree)
      end

      store_prefixes = (store_prefixes + prefixes).uniq
    else
      store_prefixes = prefixes
    end

    begin
      @lookup_context.find_template(name, store_prefixes, partial, keys, options)
    rescue ::ActionView::MissingTemplate
      @lookup_context.find_template(name, prefixes, partial, keys, options)
    end
  end
end

class ActionView::TemplateRenderer
  prepend TemplateRendererMultiStore
end
```

`spree_application` still need to go in `views/spree/layouts/<store_code>/`

Answer (score 1):

Just create an initializer multi_domain.rb with this and having two or more stores with unique codes

> store1 = Spree::Store.find_by(code: "first_store")
>
> store2 = Spree::Store.find_by(code: "second_store")

And your views separated like this:

> app/views/spree/first_store/home/index.html.erb
>
> app/views/spree/second_store/home/index.html.erb

The initializer:

```
# config/multi_domain.rb
ActionView::PartialRenderer.class_eval do
  def find_template_with_multi_store(path, locals)
    prefixes = path.include?(?/) ? [] : @lookup_context.prefixes

    store_prefixes = prefixes
    store_path     = path

    if @view.respond_to?(:current_store) && @view.current_store && !@view.controller.is_a?(Spree::Admin::BaseController)
      store_prefixes = (store_prefixes.map { |i| i.gsub('spree/', "spree/#{@view.current_store.code}/") } + store_prefixes).uniq unless store_prefixes.nil?
      store_path     = store_path.gsub('spree/', "spree/#{@view.current_store.code}/") unless store_path.nil?
    end

    begin
      @lookup_context.find_template(store_path, store_prefixes, true, locals, @details)
    rescue ::ActionView::MissingTemplate
      @lookup_context.find_template(path, prefixes, true, locals, @details)
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :find_template, :multi_store
end

ActionView::TemplateRenderer.class_eval do
  def find_template_with_multi_store(name, prefixes = [], partial = false, keys = [], options = {})
    if prefixes.nil?
      store_prefixes = nil
    elsif @view.respond_to?(:current_store) && @view.current_store && !@view.controller.is_a?(Spree::Admin::BaseController)
      spree = /^spree\//

      store_prefixes = []

      prefixes.each do |i|
        store_prefixes << i.gsub(spree, "spree/#{@view.current_store.code}/") if i.match(spree)
      end

      store_prefixes = (store_prefixes + prefixes).uniq
    else
      store_prefixes = prefixes
    end

    begin
      @lookup_context.find_template(name, store_prefixes, partial, keys, options)
    rescue ::ActionView::MissingTemplate
      @lookup_context.find_template(name, prefixes, partial, keys, options)
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :find_template, :multi_store
end
```

This implementation works in a real store with 10 domains.

Comment: This sort of works but `alias_method_chain` is deprecated now in rails 5.1.